# How to compare elements in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, slice

I'm having some trouble with an algorithm (To find the max and min values), not the algorithm itself but the implementation, let me explain:

Let's say the list is `n = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,-1,99]`; `len(n)  = 10`
Then `globalMin, globalMax = n[0], n[0]` #To skip 1 iteration from the list

And now what I have to do is compare by 'pairs', so since I already used n[0] I start comparing n[1] and n[2] to find the max and min values between those 2 and then compare it with y global min, max values, then n[3] and n[4] and compare the
nm with my global values, then n[5] and n[6] .. until I have to compare n[9] and n[10], as you can see n[10] doesn't exist on my list. I thought I could solve this with list slicing using the next code:

```
 for i in range(1, len(n), 2):

    if n[i:i+1] > n[i+1:i+2]:
      minl, maxl = n[i+1:i+2], n[i:i+1] # minl = local min; maxl = local max
    else:
      maxl, minl = n[i+1:i+2], n[i:i+1]
```

But this wont work if my last element is only one (as on the example above) so, as you can guess, If the min or max is the last element on my list it will be ignored. I have been trying to fix this with index or list slicing but no luck at all, any suggestions? I have to do this in a 'Pythonic' way and making sure to make this as simple and short as possible without using imports. I have figured the rest of the algorithm which is based on the next image: [Image](http://postimage.org/image/o5tneccql/)

Comment: I will presume you are doing this as an educational exersize, but it's worth noting that this is best achieved with `min(n), max(n)` in any real situation.

Comment: Yes, it's for educational purposes only, that's why I was asked not to use any external library or functions, it has to be only with the basic statements (if, while, elif, for, etc.)

Comment: `min()` and `max()` are built-in functions, not *external*, but I get what you mean. It's worth noting that iterating by index is inefficient, inflexible, hard to read and prone to failure, and should be avoided.

Comment: What if the number of items are odd??

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, that's why we are doing it, since we are trying to understand the O() classification for algorithms my teacher is showing us how inefficient it is to iterate through a list. 

Thanks for reminding me that those are buit-in!

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider That isn't what I mean - any method of finding the maximal/minimal value of a list will require iterating through it (presuming a non-sorted list). What I mean is that looping over a range of numbers, then using those to index the list isn't a good idea in Python - loop directly over the list instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the length of list first, if it's of odd length then you can append the last element at the end of the list. Appending is an `O(1)` operation, so, it won't affect the time complexity.

You can use a while loop:

```
In [78]: lis = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,-1]

In [79]: if len(lis)%2 !=0 :  #if the list is of odd length then append the last item to it
    lis.append(lis[-1])
   ....:     

In [80]: i=0

In [81]: while i<len(lis)-1:
    if lis[i]>lis[i+1]:
        local_max,local_min=lis[i],lis[i+1]
    elif lis[i]<lis[i+1]:    
        local_max,local_min=lis[i+1],lis[i]
    else:
        local_max,local_min=lis[i],lis[i+1]
    print local_min,local_max
    i+=2
   ....:     
0 1
1 2
3 5
8 13
-1 -1
```

or you can use an iterator:

```
In [86]: it=iter(lis)

In [87]: lis = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,-1]

In [88]: if len(lis)%2 !=0 :
    lis.append(lis[-1])
   ....:     

In [89]: it=iter(lis)

In [90]: for _ in xrange(len(lis)/2):
   ....:     a,b=next(it),next(it)
   ....:     if a>b:
   ....:         local_max,local_min=a,b
   ....:     elif a<b:    
   ....:         local_max,local_min=b,a
   ....:     else:    
   ....:         local_max,local_min=a,b
   ....:     print local_min,local_max    
   ....:     
0 1
1 2
3 5
8 13
-1 -1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much, I didn't knew about the existence of iterators. There's so much that I still don't know, thank you very much!!

Comment: This will error out if there are an odd number of items in the list. It also seems massively roundabout to use a `for` loop with `range()` to work with iterators.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue this is the most Pythonic implementation of this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

n = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, -1, 99]
global_min = global_max = n[0]

groups = [iter(n)] * 2
for a, b in zip_longest(*groups):
    if b is not None:
        if a > b:
            local_min, local_max = b, a
        else:
            local_min, local_max = a, b
    else:
        local_min = local_max = a
    if local_min < global_min:
        global_min = local_min
    if local_max > global_max:
        global_max = local_max

print(global_min, global_max)
```

We group the items by using [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) ([`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in 2.x) and a list of the same iterator repeated. We then loop over this, which gives us the values in pairs. We then do a check, if the value is the last one, we assign it as the `local_min` and `local_max`, otherwise, we compare the two values and assign as appropriate.

We then compare (and potentially update) `global_min` and `global_max`.